# GNOME 3.6 lockscreen from Unity

Tags: gnome, lock-screen

I would like the GNOME 3.6 lockscreen (GDM 3.6.1) to be called from  Unity. I am not a expert, but my impression is that the lockscreen is part of GDM as opposed to gnome shell. If this is true (again, I am not sure about that), then how can I get that lockscreen to be called from within Unity? I already set GDM in place of lightDM.

Thank you!

Comment: Have to tried using 'Ctrl' + 'Alt' + 'L' or 'Super' + 'L'?

Comment: Yes, it brings up the old one (blackscreen+dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I looked through the code for GNOME, and apparently the lock-screen is written into gnome-shell, not just GDM. I feel like this is bad design, but who am I to tell them how to program?